# How to export CSV file with more than 1,048,576 rows of data via powershell

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, filesystems

As you know Excel has got 1048574 rows. How can I export more than one million rows below my code ? if max rows is reached then how can I continue over new worksheet in Loop ? how to adapted it? 
I'm googling some after I find nice [powershell functions](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) it.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OOXML.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll")

$wb = New-Object NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook;
$ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions");
$wr = $ws.CreateRow(0);



$wr.createCell(0).setCellValue("Folder Path");
$wr.createCell(1).setCellValue("Users/Groups");
$wr.createCell(2).setCellValue("Permissions");
$wr.createCell(3).setCellValue("AccessControlType");
$wr.createCell(4).setCellValue("Permissions Inherited")



$dirToAudit = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\inetpub" -recurse | Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }

$intRow = 1

foreach ($dir in $dirToAudit)
{
    $colACL = Get-Acl -Path $dir.FullName

    foreach ($acl in $colACL)
    {
        $fileNameRow = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
        $fileNameRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue($dir.FullName)
        $intRow++

        foreach ($accessRight in $acl.Access)
        {
            $values = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
            $values.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.IdentityReference).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.FileSystemRights).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.AccessControlType).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue($($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected).ToString())
            $intRow++

        }
    }

}
$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream("C:\DRIVERS\test.xlsx",[System.IO.FileMode]'Create',[System.IO.FileAccess]'Write')
$wb.Write($fs);
$fs.Close()
```

Comment: You're already keeping track of the number of rows in `$intRow` so can't you just check if you've just reached the row limit then re-assign your worksheet variable like `$ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Next_Sheet");`?

Comment: how can I adapted variable like $ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Next_Sheet") ? please clarify me

Comment: You set the variable for the worksheet at the top of the code, and that variable determines everything about what sheet the data is added to. Just re-set that variable later in code to a different worksheet (the exact line I posted, but change the variable name from "Next_Sheet"), and all new data will be added to that different sheet.

Comment: $wb = New-Object NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook;
$ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions");
$ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions_2");
$wr = $ws.CreateRow(0);   Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your existing knowledge of the current row number to determine when the max row is reached, then move to a new sheet.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OOXML.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\DRIVERS\NPOI 2.2.1 binary package\Release\Net40\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll")

$wb = New-Object NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook;
$ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions");
$wr = $ws.CreateRow(0);



$wr.createCell(0).setCellValue("Folder Path");
$wr.createCell(1).setCellValue("Users/Groups");
$wr.createCell(2).setCellValue("Permissions");
$wr.createCell(3).setCellValue("AccessControlType");
$wr.createCell(4).setCellValue("Permissions Inherited")



$dirToAudit = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\inetpub" -recurse | Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }

$maxRow = 1048576
$intRow = 1
$intNextSheet = 2

foreach ($dir in $dirToAudit)
{
    $colACL = Get-Acl -Path $dir.FullName

    foreach ($acl in $colACL)
    {
        $fileNameRow = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
        $fileNameRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue($dir.FullName)
        $intRow++

        if ($intRow -eq $maxRow)
        {
            $ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions" + $intNextSheet);
            $intNextSheet++
            $intRow = 0
        }

        foreach ($accessRight in $acl.Access)
        {
            $values = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
            $values.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.IdentityReference).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.FileSystemRights).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.AccessControlType).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue($($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected).ToString())
            $intRow++

            if ($intRow -eq $maxRow)
            {
                $ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions" + $intNextSheet);
                $intNextSheet++
                $intRow = 0
            }
        }
    }

}
$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream("C:\DRIVERS\test.xlsx",[System.IO.FileMode]'Create',[System.IO.FileAccess]'Write')
$wb.Write($fs);
$fs.Close()
```

The important bit here:

```
if ($intRow -eq $maxRow)
{
    $ws = $wb.CreateSheet("Company_NTFS_Permissions" + $intNextSheet);
    $intNextSheet++
    $intRow = 0
}
```

This runs after each time `$intRow` gets incremented, checking whether the `$maxRow` has been reached. If so, it moves to a new sheet with a numbered name and restarts from the first row.

Comment: thanks man but I assuming there is logical error because normally I fetching NTFS permissions with 169 rows at this time your modified code 169  worksheets creating instead of this  So it doesnt working  Max limit logical

Comment: Yep, made a mistake forgetting what language I was in. Comparisons use `-eq` in Powershell. I've edited the answer to reflect the change.